# Tabris, Eclipse RAP How can i trigger an UIUpdate?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rap

How can i trigger an UIUpdate with Tabris ? JavaScript ? UICallback ? Can you give a little example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a UICallback mechanism (called ServerPush in RAP 2.0).
On the RAP wiki page is more information on that topic: http://wiki.eclipse.org/RAP/UI_Callback